# How can I add member in mongoDB replicationset?

Tags: mongodb, replication, mongodb-replica-set, mongodb-replica

I am config replication with `rs.initiate()` command then after I try to add a member to my server IP address using `rs.add(xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017)` but it's return error like this.

> {     "ok" : 0,   "errmsg" : "Quorum check failed because not enough
>   voting nodes responded; required 2 but only the following 1 voting
>   nodes responded: xxx.xxx.xxx.01:27017; the following nodes did not
>   respond affirmatively: xxx.xxx.xxx.02:27017 failed with Server min and
>   max wire version are incompatible (0,5) with client min wire version
>   (6,6)",   "code" : 74,    "codeName" : "NodeNotFound",    "operationTime" :
>   Timestamp(1516699107, 1),     "$clusterTime" : {      "clusterTime" :
>   Timestamp(1516699107, 1),         "signature" : {             "hash" :
>   BinData(0,"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="),            "keyId" : NumberLong(0)
>         }   } }

Please give me solution for that.

Thanks!

-Karmdip Joshi

Comment: Looks like one of your replicas are out of date

Comment: But how both replica is on my local server and it's possible then  how replica is expired plz explain me if you can cz i didn't know about it.

Comment: do a rs.status() - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/rs.status/

Comment: yes I am checking with this command it shows me my localhost is on member list but I can't add another server IP to members list using rs.add()

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution of this.

It's just MongoDB version issue.

My primary server configuration is.

> MongoDB shell version v3.6.2

And My secondary server configuration is.

> MongoDB shell version v3.4.10

I am updating my secondary server to v3.6.2 and I can add my secondary server IP in a member of my replica set using `rs.add()` and it's working good.

Thanks for the support.

-Karmdip Joshi

Answer (score 0):

Two things...

First, check firewalls! Every node must have a possibility to connect to other nodes.

Second, you cannot use localhost address(es) if all nodes are NOT at same computer. So, if you are already configured first node using localhost address, you cannot add other nodes with IP addresses, all addresses must be (in that case) localhost i.e. same computer but different port.

Comment: Hello JJussi, I also disabled firewalls and my first node using my local IP but I still return this error.

Comment: Thanks JJussi, I solved this issue and also wrote same in the answer. and I think you have seen my answer.